# 'for' loop used for array not working in this simple script

Tags: javascript, arrays

See the following code:

```
function overall() {
var message = ["dog", "cat", "bear", "penguin", "tiger", "eagle", "John Doe"];
function forward() {
    var A = document.getElementById('text');
    for (var i = 0; i < message.length+1; i++) {
        if (A.innerHTML===message[i]) {
            A.innerHTML = message[i+1];
        };
    };
};
function backward() {
    var A = document.getElementById('text');
    for (var i = 0; i < message.length+1; i++) {
        if (A.innerHTML===message[i]) {
            A.innerHTML = message[i-1];
        };
    };
};
};
```

In the above JS script, my intention is when the forward() function is called, animal in the '.innerHTML' should change to an animal after that one in the array called 'message' using the for loop.
Similarly, when the backward() function is called, animal in the '.innerHTML' should change to an animal before that one in the said array.

I verified my script and there are, supposedly, no syntactical errors. That means there is an error in my logic. Please help me out. Thanks!

The HTML:

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
   <p id="text">dog</p>
   <div id='right' onclick="forward()"></div>
   <div id="left" onclick="backward()"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `message.length+1` will cause the loop to run past the end of the array. You probably meant `message.length-1`.

Comment: Please add the HTML of this element, and the code where you actually call `forward` and `backward`.

Comment: how do you call your function in your HTML ? i mean the two function are included in an overall function.

Comment: First of all you shouldn't set `onclick` callbacks by invoking. Do it like `<div id='right' onclick="forward"></div>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This help you :

```html
<html>
<head>
    <style>
    </style>
</head>
    <body>
        <p id="text">cat</p>
        <button id="btn1" onclick="forward()">Next</button>
        <button id="btn2" onclick="backward()">previous</button>
        <script>
                    var message = ["dog", "cat", "bear", "penguin", "tiger", "eagle", "John Doe"];
                    function forward() {
                        var A = document.getElementById('text');
                        for (var i = 0; i < message.length-1; i++) {
                            if (A.innerHTML === message[i]) {
                                A.innerHTML = message[i+1];
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    function backward() {
                        var A = document.getElementById('text');
                        for (var i = message.length-1; i > 0; i--) {
                            if (A.innerHTML===message[i]) {
                                A.innerHTML = message[i-1];
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                    }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You will never be able to call neither `forward` nor `backward` since they are wrapped inside another function (`overall`) and you don't return them in any way. They are private. You are not calling them even inside the `overall` function so what you've shown here is basically a dead code :)

As a side note: why are you putting semicolon `;` after `for`, `if` and `function` statements???

Comment: Great, thanks! Also, I put the semi-colons just for personal satisfaction; that their actions are over. Does it affect the script as a whole?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want do this

```js
var message = ["dog", "cat", "bear", "penguin", "tiger", "eagle", "John Doe"];
function forward() {
    var A = document.getElementById('text');
    for (var i = 0; i < message.length; i++) {
        if (A.innerHTML===message[i]) {
            break;
        }
    }
    if(i+1 == message.length) return false;
    A.innerHTML = message[i+1];
};
function backward() {
    var A = document.getElementById('text');
    for (var i = 0; i < message.length; i++) {
        if (A.innerHTML===message[i]) {
          break;
        }
    }
    if(i == 0) return false;
    A.innerHTML = message[i-1];
};
```

```html
   <p id="text">dog</p>
   <button id='right' onclick="forward()">right</button>
   <button id="left" onclick="backward()">left</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to stop the loop when you change the Node.

For example, the initial text is `tiger`. You call `forward()`. The loop starts, and for `i=4` it goes inside the if, changes the text in `#text` to `eagle`. Next iteration, `i=5`, `eagle === eagle`, you set `John Doe` etc...

All you have to do is to stop the loop after the first change:

```
if (A.innerHTML===message[i]) {
    A.innerHTML = message[i+1];
    break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you should have used break once you hit a matching text.

```
   var message = ["dog", "cat", "bear", "penguin", "tiger", "eagle", "John Doe"];
function forward() {

      var A = document.getElementById('text');
      for (var i = 0; i < message.length-1; i++) {
          if (A.innerHTML===message[i]) {
              A.innerHTML = message[i+1];
              break;
          }
      }

}
function backward() {

       var A = document.getElementById('text');
       for (var i = 0; i < message.length-1; i++) {
       if (A.innerHTML===message[i]) {
        A.innerHTML = message[i-1];
        break;
    }
}

  }
```

here is the plunker https://plnkr.co/edit/rcCIEUejlxog2RkqHkwa?p=preview

Now call backward and forward as you like. But you need to check for first and last position as well since calling a backward function with dog as the text in element A will cause the text to be undefined. If you want the text to be revolving then that can be handled as well.

Answer (score 0):

Well i would do this job with a single callback applicable both for the forward and reverse buttons (divs here)

```js
var message = ["dog", "cat", "bear", "penguin", "tiger", "eagle", "John Doe"],
        pel = document.getElementById("text"),
        idx = 0,
    getNext = e => pel.innerText = e.target.id == "right" ? message[idx = ++idx%message.length]
                                                          : message[idx = (message.length - (message.length - --idx)%message.length)%message.length];
document.getElementById("right").onclick = getNext;
document.getElementById("left").onclick = getNext;
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="script.js" defer ></script>
  </head>

  <body>
   <p id="text">dog</p>
   <div id="right" style = "background-color:tomato" onclick="getNext">Forward</div>
   <div id="left" style = "background-color:thistle" onclick="getNext">Backward</div>
  </body>

</html>
```

However i can not make sure if this is the best way to get reverse modulus on array indices when pressed backwards. I would appreciate guidance on a better approach.

By the way, I know that arrows are not OK with IE and Safari but one may easily replace them with their conventional counterparts.

Answer (score -2):

```js
function overall() {
var message = ["dog", "cat", "bear", "penguin", "tiger", "eagle", "John Doe"];
function forward() {
    var A = document.getElementById('text');
    for (var i = 0; i < message.length; i++) {
        if (A.innerHTML===message[i] && i < message.length-1) { 
            A.innerHTML = message[i+1];
        };
    };
};
function backward() {
    var A = document.getElementById('text');
    for (var i = 0; i < message.length; i++) {
        if (A.innerHTML === message[i] && i > 0) {
            A.innerHTML = message[i-1];
        };
    };
};
};
```

Comment: You should explain what you've changed in the code snippet. Pure code answers are discouraged.

Comment: Array index start from zero and array.length start from one and the loop should be i < array.length and also in if condition should be what i wrote